# Wifi not connecting on click on list view item

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am creating an application in which I want to switch between two WIFI. I have already configured both the two WIFI manually from WIFI settings in device. Now only I want to connect the WIFI from SSID.

from below code I am connecting wifi.

```
wifiList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
                    connectToWifi("Android Keeda", "nida1234");
            }
        });
```

I am calling below function in setOnItemClickListener and when I click on list view item then current WIFI disconnected but within second it is connect with last connected WIFI network and not connecting with WIFI name given in function parameter. How can I achieve this ?

```
private void connectToWifi(String ssid, String password)
    {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            try {
                Log.e("TAG","connection wifi pre Q");
                WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
                wifiConfig.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";
                int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();

            } catch ( Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG","connection wifi  Q");

            WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                    .setSsid( ssid )
                    .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                    .build();

            NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                    .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
                    .build();

            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


            ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                    super.onAvailable(network);

                    connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                    Log.e("TAG","onAvailable");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLosing(@NonNull Network network, int maxMsToLive) {
                    super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive);
                    Log.e("TAG","onLosing");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLost(Network network) {
                    super.onLost(network);
                    Log.e("TAG", "losing active connection");
                }

                @Override
                public void onUnavailable() {
                    super.onUnavailable();
                    Log.e("TAG","onUnavailable");
                }
            };
            connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest,networkCallback);


        }
    }
```

Comment: You are adding "" to the password. instead of trying nida1234 it tries "nida1234" (with qoutes)

Comment: Thanks @Dan for your reply. I have tried but still connecting with last connected network

Comment: Well, first of all, are you targeting Q or lower? so we will know which part of the code to focus on

Comment: I am targeting both Android Q and lower